# Notice:Undefined index error

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm getting this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: prospectname in C:\wamp\www\var\SAS\insert.php on line 12
```

Here is the code

```
<form action="#" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-bordered'>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="prospectname" class="control-label">Prospect Name</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="prospectname" id="prospectname" placeholder="prospectname" class="input-xlarge">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label for="status" class="control-label">Status</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

sas.js

```
$(".registeradd").click(function () {

    var prospectname = $("#prospectname").val();
    var status = $("#status").val();
    var dataString = 'prospectname =' + prospectname + '&status=' + status;

    if (prospectname == '') {
        alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    } else {
        $("#flash").show();
        $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $("#display").after(html);
                $("#flash").hide();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Insert.php

```
<?php

$dbHost = 'localhost'; // usually localhost
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = '';
$dbDatabase = 'test';

$db = mysql_connect($dbHost, $dbUsername, $dbPassword) or die ("Unable to connect to Database Server.");

mysql_select_db ($dbDatabase, $db) or die ("Could not select database.");

$prospectname =$_POST['prospectname'];
$status=$_POST['status'];

$sql_insert="insert into salesactivity(prospectname,status) values '$prospectname','$status')";

print $sql_insert;
mysql_query($sql_insert);

?>
```

Comment: You are vurnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Did you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your datastring

```
var dataString = 'prospectname ='+ prospectname +'&status='+status;
```

to a `json object`

```
var dataString = { 'prospectname': prospectname, 'status': status};
```

Answer (score -1):

i think you forget status text field in your form  add it on html form

```
replace your form with this



  <form action="#" method="POST" class='form-horizontal form-bordered'>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label for="prospectname" class="control-label">Prospect Name</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="prospectname" id="prospectname" placeholder="prospectname" class="input-xlarge">
                </div>
            </div>

              <div class="control-group">
                <label for="prospectname" class="control-label">Status</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" name="status" id="status" placeholder="status" class="input-xlarge">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```